# Make jQuery Captify show images captions permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caption

Is there a way to show captions for images permanently on page load, not only when I move mouse cursor over the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a field animation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.captify').captify({
    speedOver: 'fast',
    speedOut: 'normal',
    hideDelay: 500,
    animation: 'always-on',
    prefix: '',
    opacity: '0.7',
    className: 'caption-bottom',
    position: 'bottom',
    spanWidth: '100%'
    });
});
```

It can be slide, fade and always-on. So the last one is the right choice.